# how to create a folder in my google drive through google colab code?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to using google colab. My code creates a file but right now I have to manually create the folder it is placed in before running the code every time. Is there a line of code that will create a folder in my google drive (which is mounted) in the same way it would a file? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you try to use python for this - ie. `os.makedirs()`. it should work in any situation. Eventually in Google Colab may works `"magic commands"` which let you execute Linux/Bash command with `!` like `!ls -al`, `!mkdir folder`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After mounting Google Drive in Google Colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I have no problem to create it with Python

```
import os

os.makedirs('/content/drive/MyDrive/my_folder')
```

and see it

```
list(os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive'))
```

I can also use `Linux/Bash` command for this - with `"magic command"` using `!`

```
!mkdir /content/drive/MyDrive/my_folder
```

and see it

```
!ls -al /content/drive/MyDrive
```